# Rest API Javascript client authentication without exposing credentials

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, authentication

I developed a REST API using PHP. I'm now creating a JS client for that API, my problem is how do I authenticate the API without sharing the key and secret in my JS Code?

I was thinking about sending the key and validating the HTTP Referrer header for the domain, but this is really not safe since the header can be changed.